# What is the legal status of US 2013/0132813 A1?

Tags: legal-status, us20130132813

I am researching on this field and need to know the current status of this patent? Can someone let me know the state?

In reference to the patent: [US 2013/0132813 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130132813)

Answer (score 1):

This application is still undergoing prosecution. A Final Rejection was issued by the USPTO on April 2, 2015 based on non-statutory subject matter and a lack of definitions in the specification. However, a Notice of Appeal was filed on July 21, 2015.

Updated information, including all correspondence between the examiner and inventor is freely available in the USPTO [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) database.